# Cache context in Spring test even if it failed to load

Tags: java, spring, testing, junit, spring-test

As mentioned in http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/testing.html#testcontext-ctx-management-caching, Spring will always tries to cache test contexts according to some generated key.

But, is there a way to cache a test context that **failed** to load? In other words -- if a test context *failed* to load, I do *not* want further tests to re-attempt loading it. In fact, they should just fail immediately with the same error that caused the initial context loading attempt to fail.

So, is there a way to do this in Spring? E.g., if I try to load a context whose "generated key" is the same as a previous one that failed to load, just fail *immediately* with the same error that the initial context loading attempt failed with/.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, as of Spring Framework 4.0.5 there is no mechanism for caching a *failed* `ApplicationContext`.

If this is a feature you would like to see introduced in the Spring TestContext Framework, please [create a JIRA issue](https://jira.spring.io/secure/CreateIssue!default.jspa) for the "Spring Framework" project and "Test" component.

Regards,

Sam (author of the Spring TestContext Framework)

Answer (score 0):

One solution to this would be to create you're own ContextLoader and override the loadContext method. For example, for a test using WebAppConfiguration, you could override  WebDelegatingSmartContextLoader with something along the lines of

```
public class FastFailContextLoader extends WebDelegatingSmartContextLoader {
    private static boolean initialized = false;

    @Override
    public ApplicationContext loadContext(MergedContextConfiguration mergedConfig) throws Exception {
        if (initialized) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(
                    "The ApplicationContext has already attempted to initialize. Aborting subsequent initialization. Check "
                            + "earlier logs for original error");
        }
        setInitialized();
        return super.loadContext(mergedConfig);
    }

    private static void setInitialized() {
        initialized = true;
    }
}
```

Then you just need to annotate your test with

```
@ContextConfiguration(loader = FastFailContextLoader.class)
```